# Java Based Augmented Reality Framework?

Tags: java, augmented-reality

I wanted to know the existing Augmented Reality Frameworks in Java. I would like to develop some interactive **desktop** applications related to Augmented Reality. What are the required Frameworks?

Comment: I'm quite sure there is a version of ARToolkit written in Java. I don't remember the name and if it is only for Android OS. Try to google for it.

Comment: Actually after searching stack overflow the forum is filled with frameworks facilitating android. I am searching for desktop application.

Comment: @Heisenbug I will but is it possible to make an application? For desktop? I would like to have the projection of entire thing through a projector onto a wall to create a virtual environment where people can interact with the object!

Comment: I don't know. I'm sure about Android Java version of ARToolkit. I don't know for desktops.

Comment: @Heisenbug can you suggest some tutorials where we can begin learning about different concepts of Augmented reality and learn about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

have a look at http://nyatla.jp/nyartoolkit/wp/ it's a ARToolkit port mostley written in Java and I've used it for android and desktop applications. If you want to get realy fast started, try out [processing](http://processing.org) and NyAR4psg.

all other libraries I'm aware of are mostly written in c(++).

here are some other c++ frameworks I’m aware of:

- http://www.artoolworks.com/
- http://www.icg.tugraz.at/project/studierstube

Comment: Can I get some tutorials for easy understanding of Augmented Reality with some demo?

Comment: please try a google search on "nyartoolkit processing", i can't give you better links. for simple examples look at the nyar4psg processing demos

Comment: thanks for paving the path. Nice link. Need to try out this thing!! :)